# Monitor and limit network usage

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, firewall

A costumer of mine has some off site locations, where his internet usage is supplied by a cellular router. The router is connected to a switch and a WiFi hotspot.

The client has a problem with excessive internet usage, and he doesn't know why. Now he want's a ticket like system, where each worker using the hotspot gets a predefined number of GB's worth of usage. But mostly the client want's to know why his internet usage is excessive. So basically a firewall with monitoring capabilities would do the trick.

The gathered stats should start from the 1. of each month.
The tickets should be revoked the 1. of each month.

Is there any firewall solution capable of these requirements?

Comment: You are not able to set bandwidth in the WIFI hotspot configuration ?

Comment: Not with the current hardware. But the client needs to monitor the INTERNET usage. Not the wifi specific usage.